# kafka + how to disable/delete the segment.bytes from the topic

Tags: apache-kafka

we have Kafka version - `0.1`

from Kafka describe we can verify the `segment.bytes` , `retention.ms` , `retention.bytes`

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper01:2181 --describe|grep  my_first_car
Topic:my_first_car        PartitionCount:100      ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:segment.bytes=344778,retention.ms=1780000,retention.bytes=271641765
        Topic: my_first_car       Partition: 0    Leader: 1011    Replicas: 1011,1010,1009        Isr: 1011,1010,1009
```

is it possible to disable/delete the `segment.bytes` from the topic?

**Expected results:**

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper01:2181 --describe|grep  my_first_car
Topic:my_first_car        PartitionCount:100      ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:retention.ms=1780000,retention.bytes=271641765
        Topic: my_first_car       Partition: 0    Leader: 1011    Replicas: 1011,1010,1009        Isr: 1011,1010,1009
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

```
kafka-topics ... --alter \
   --entity-type topics --entity-name <topic-name> \
   --delete-config 'segment.bytes'
```

However, there is a default applied on the server-side, and you therefore cannot completely remove that config

Comment: I think you should fix it to --> /kafka-configs.sh --alter --zookeeper zookeeper01:2181  --entity-type topics  --entity-name <topic-name> --delete-config    'segment.bytes'

Comment: Zookeeper flag is deprecated. That's why I left it out